# Set specific card caption Layout View Devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

I use Devexpress Grid Control with Layout View. I want to set only one card caption when it is newly added (for example "new card") and when card lose focus to set caption back to default ("Record [x of x]")

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are trying to provide a specific caption for a new card. If so I suggest you review the following [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center)'s thread, where this issue has already discussed: [How to change card caption for a new card](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q210810).

Related help articles:
[Card Caption](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument3442)
[Localizing WinForms Controls via Localizer Objects](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1866)